# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined (REACTJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am still new to Reactjs, thought have tried all I can, but still can't get through this error **"`TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`"**
please someone help below is my code.

```
if(this.props.controller === 'location'){  

   eventData = Object.keys(this.props.heda).map( evKey => {

        return Object.keys(evKey).map( post => {

            return [...Array(this.props.heda[evKey][post])].map( lol => {

                    return  <Event key= {lol['id']}          
                    descriptions = {lol['description']}
                    headings = {lol['title']}
                    id = {lol['id']} 
                    clicked = { ()=> this.viewSelectedEvent(lol['id']) }/>;

            }) ; 

        });

    });

}
```

Error full stacktrace:

[image]

here is my data from flask that am trying to loop.Am trying to convert each object into an array, then loop through the array. I also tried to console.log(lol)  and i get the data as in the image below
    [image: data is available]

```
 events = [
        {
          'id': 1,
          'title': u'HHGHHMjshjskksjks',
          'description': u'Cras justo odio dapibus ac facilisis in egestas eget qua ', 
          'location':'jkknxjnj',
          'category':'party',
          'rsvp': False,
          'event_owner':1
        },

        {
          'id': 2,
          'title': u'khjhjshjsjhdndjdh',
          'description': u'jhhnbsbnsbj', 
          'location':'jhjhsjhjhsjhjdhsd',
          'category':'party',
          'rsvp': False,
          'event_owner':2
        },

        {
          'id': 3,
          'title': u'jhjshjsdhjshdjshjsd',
          'description': u'Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec  elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.', 
          'location':'kjkshjhjhjbsnbsd',
          'category':'party',
          'rsvp': False,
          'event_owner':2
        },

        {
          'id': 4,
          'title': u'jjhjshjhsjhjshjjhjhd',
          'description': u'Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec  elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.', 
          'location':'kjisisiisdsds',
          'category':'party',
          'rsvp': False,
          'event_owner':2
          },

          {
            'id': 5,
            'title': u'uiujsdshuuihuyksjhjs',
            'description': u'Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec  elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.', 
            'location':'sjnsisuis',
            'category':'party',
            'rsvp': False,
            'event_owner':2
          },

          {
          'id': 6,
          'title': u'iusijksuiksuhj suyuys jhu ',
          'description': u'Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec  elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.', 
          'location':'isuisiiws',
          'category':'party',
          'rsvp': False,
          'event_owner':2
          },

          {
          'id': 7,
          'title': u'jujusi jsuoios jshuysd',
          'description': u'Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec  elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.', 
          'location':'area h',
          'category':'party',
          'rsvp': False,
          'event_owner':2
          },
    ]
```

Comment: What is this construct `[...Array(this.props.heda[evKey][post])]` supposed to return?

Comment: The error most likely means that your `lol` data is undefined. And this happens, because `this.props.heda[evKey][post]` is not a correct array, that I think, because of incorrect usage of `Object.keys(evKey)`, I think it's not doing  what you are expect. So, just put `console.log` after each line, and check, where you have a correct data, and where it broken. (or debug it )

Comment: i get the data if i try to console.log(lol)

Answer (score 1):

With `[...Array(this.props.heda[evKey][post])]` you create an array which has as the first element the array `this.props.heda[evKey][post])`.

Maybe you wanted to say `[...this.props.heda[evKey][post]]` to create a clone of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Because he is not able to find id in `this.props.heda[evKey][post]` object. So firstly you should console your `this.props.heda[evKey][post]` object after that I think you will get your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below snippet:

```
this.props.heda.map((evVal, evKey) => {
    return evVal.map((postVal, postKey) => {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now this.props.heda[evKey][postKey] will give you the expected object.